# Sum symbol length

Tags: displaystyle, lipsum

I would like to put a big sum in the following equation.

```
\begin{align}
R_t\,B_t=\displaystyle{\sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \frac{ T^{\star}_{t+s}}{\displaystyle\prod_{\tau=1}^{s}}}-\displaystyle{\sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \frac{ G_{t+s}}{\displaystyle\prod_{\tau=1}^{s}}}-\displaystyle{\sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \frac{ E_{t+s}}{\displaystyle\prod_{\tau=1}^{s}}}-
\end{align}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! If you want someone to help you, you should post a complete [minimal working example MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) beginning at `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, including all packages and commands necessary to compile your code and create the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `\mathlarger` command from the `relsize` package.

Please mind that I tweaked your example:

1. I removed the `align` environment since you're not aligning, and replaced it with an unnumbered equation (`\[`…`\]`) from the `amsmath` package
2. I got rid of the `displaystyle` commands since they were useless imo, and I feel that the equation is better off without them
3. I inserted a space `\:` after the large sums to give breadth to the expressions which, otherwise, felt cramped.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,relsize}
\begin{document}
\[
R_t\,B_t=\mathlarger{\sum}_{s=0}^{\infty}\: \frac{ T^{\star}_{t+s}}{\prod_{\tau=1}^{s}}-\mathlarger{\sum}_{s=0}^{\infty} \:\frac{ G_{t+s}}{\prod_{\tau=1}^{s}}-\mathlarger{\sum}_{s=0}^{\infty}\: \frac{ E_{t+s}}{\prod_{\tau=1}^{s}}
\]
\end{document}
```

and the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can resize by simply using `\scaleobj{}{}` command present in `\usepackage{scalerel}[2016/12/29]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2016/12/29]

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
R_t\,B_t=\displaystyle{\scaleobj{2}{\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}} \frac{ T^{\star}_{t+s}}  {\displaystyle\prod_{\tau=1}^{s}}}-\displaystyle{\scaleobj{2}{\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}} \frac{ G_{t+s}} {\displaystyle\prod_{\tau=1}^{s}}}-\displaystyle{\scaleobj{2}{\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}} \frac{ E_{t+s}} {\displaystyle\prod_{\tau=1}^{s}}}-
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]